# How to set continue text or data in multiple PDF page Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pdf, uigraphicscontext

I have created multiple PDF pages in inside a scroll view. But from page 2, the data or texts are duplicated. The content is the same with page 1 and I can continue the text or data. This is my PDF generation code:

```
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, _tableView.bounds, nil);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGFloat screensInTable = _tableView.contentSize.height / _tableView.height;

for (int i = 1; i < screensInTable; i++) {
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(_tableView.bounds, nil);
    CGPoint contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, i * _tableView.height);
    [_tableView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];
    [_tableView.layer renderInContext:context];
}

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```